# Do not let users to do multiple uploads

Tags: php, upload

I have an uploading script and i want to restrict users to 1 upload each time and not multiple uploads. how i can implement it in php ? because the main problem is that if i assign a value in database to show if user is uploading a file then if user closes the page without upload being complete, he/she will not be able to upload another file because script thinks that he/she is uploading one already.

Is there any idea on how can i implement it ?

Comment: Show us your code. You're basically asking "how long is a piece of string"?

Comment: I'm trying to modify this : http://adv-uploads.svn.sourceforge.net/ I don't let user to upload more than one on each page, but if he opens multiple page/tabs then he will be to do that.

Comment: We can't go out and `fetch` the code(s) for you. Post your code(s) that you are having trouble with.

Comment: I explain my problem : i want to execute a database update on page closure or a little after it to change user state from uploading to idle. and i don't want a code, i want an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Have a table for 'session / user' with 'upload started' and 'upload finished' columns. Don't populate the second until you are sure you are done. Don't start a new upload if you have a record with an empty 'finished' field for that user.

To keep from blocking someone who has disconnected before completing - either periodically check to see if a given session is still active or purge sessions that are older than a certain amount of time.

Comment: So as i thought certain amount of time for these checks are necessary, am i right ? cause i searched a little and find out some JS commands to execute on page closure but i think those are unreliable specially when user has disabled JS.

Comment: I would think you could guess from regular usage what constitutes 'long enough'.